# How should I call functions defined outside of the main function?

Tags: python, algorithm, function, python-3.x, nested

So I'm fairly new to python and I am working on an algorithm and I have let's say 2 functions

```
func1(x)

func2(x)
```

already defined outside the main function.

Now I want to call these functions inside the main functions one nested inside the other

Something like this

```
def funcmain(func1(func2(x)))
```

It obviously is not working I haven't been able to get it work anyway I want. Any tips on this?

**Edit:** What I meant to do is that I want to input a string, I want it to go through func2 first, then the return value from func2 to go through func1 and finally the return value of func1 to go through func main. I have tested each function separately and they are working as intended but I can't seem to get them interlinked together

Comment: Er... That's invalid syntax. Why would you want to invoke the functions when you're trying to declare the arguments of a third one?

Comment: you cannot pass a function as an un-named argument

Comment: What I meant to do is that I want to input a string, I want it to go through func2 first, then the return value from func2 to go through func1 and finally the return value of func1 to go through func main. I have tested each function separately and they are working as intended but I can't seem to get them interlinked together

Answer (score 3):

I hope this code snippet will help to clarify things for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def func1(x):
    return x + 1

def func2(x):
    return x + 2

def main(x):
    print func1(func2(x))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(0)
```

The output is 3.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?  Your question is not too clear.  I assume x is also defined globally somewhere.

```
def funcmain():
    return func1(func2(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

take the following functions:

```
def func1(x):
    return x+1


def func2(x):
    return x*2
```

by itself you COULD do this: `func1(func2(3))` which would return 3 times 2 plus 1. This works because by itself `func1(func2(3))` actually returns a value, not a function.

BUT since you are trying to put it as the basic argument for the main function like this:

```
def main(func1(func2(x))): #dont do this, this is what you did, it is bad
    return x*3
```

its not going to know what to do with that because there is no default for x...

you CAN DO THIS THOUGH:

```
def main(x=func1(func2(1)):
    return x*3
```

this would do the appropriate math to 1 and then assign it as x (Because as we saw earlier, func1(func2(3))` would return THE RESULT OF FUNCTIONS not a function itself, then multiply it by 3. since you are defaulting x to equal a value ( which is func1(func2(1))

This is bad practice still, because you are defaulting to whatever `func1(func2(1)` comes out to.

what you probably want in the end is something simpler:

```
def main(x):
     y = func1(func2(x))
     return y*3
```

or maybe even simpler than that

```
def main(x):
    return x*3

#and then just call it like this
main(func1(func2(1))
```

Comment: Don't do that. That's declaring `main`'s argument with a default value and that doesn't seem to be whay OP wanted.

Comment: It's not about bad practice or it being "bad" - in many contexts that would be totally fine, but it's simply not what the OP wants. Introducing keyword arguments just makes your answer more confusing. And the last example totally defeats the point of the convention of a `main()` function (a main entry point from where everything else gets called).